# Python - list comprehension over tuple

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have two arrays inside tuple and need to iterate over it.

```
recs = ([1,2,3], [4,5,6])
[print(f, s) for f, s in recs]
```

But got error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

How can I do it?

P.S. print only for debug example

Comment: That doesn't sound like you need to explicitly iterate at all (and it's definitely not a job for a list comprehension; those are for building lists). This sounds like you just want `print(*recs)`, or `print(recs)`.

Comment: What is your expected output? Also note that using `print` in a list comprehension will generate a list full of `None` which is likely not what you were intending (other than to achieve the side effect of printing in the meanwhile)

Comment: Output is : 1, 4 2, 5 3, 6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`zip` is the function you're after:

```
_ = [print(*values, end=' ') for values in zip(*recs)]
```

`values` here is the `(f, s)` tuple. This way it will generalize beyond just 2 lists